# how can I update the cell in Sheet1 using associated cell in Sheet2 is edited

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have google spreadsheet contains 2 sheets, Sheet1 & Sheet2. We get data from external source into Sheet1. We'll get data into Sheet2 using google QUERY based on Filters (filter1,2,3) selection.

I want to edit comment section in sheet2 for example in D7 its 'Out of Stock', wants to change to 'In stock' which then reflect back in Sheet1 . Please check attached screenshot.

Methods I tried is adding additional column at E, when we enter anything in E7 and hit ENTER it reflect back in sheet1 and also in sheet2.

Was there anyway to edit comment section in same cell/column without any additional column like I mentioned above?

Also tried Appscript didn't workout as expected.

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the data from external source to sheet1? Is it using importrange or is it manually being copied? Because if it is using importrange then you can't edit the data from sheet1 if it is being pulled directly from the external source. Another is you can not edit the sheet2 data if it being produced by `query()` from sheet1. If possible please share a sample or copy of your spreadsheet, so we can replicate what you have. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: Hard to know what you want without more clarity but you could do one-way sync to **`Sheet1!C1`** based on matching **`ID`** as follows: **`={"Comment"; IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(TOCOL(C2:C,1), FILTER(Sheet2!B7:D, Sheet2!B7:B<>""), 3, 0)), "**MISSING ID**")}`** If you want 2-way or 3-way syncing you'll need a script.  Please [edit] your question to be more clear.

Comment: I'll share sheet please allow sometime @logan

Answer (score 0):

For every edit of sheet 2 the same cell is updated in sheet 1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet2" &&  e.range.rowStart > 6 && e.range.columnStart > 1) {
    let sh1 = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sh1.getRange(e.range.rowStart - 5, e.range.columnStart - 1).setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```